# CSS brightness/contrast at the server side

Tags: php, css, image, graphics, imagemagick

Looking for answer for 2 weeks. I have a tool which allows to adjust images' contrast and brightness directly in the web browser and use CSS3 properties to show result. But I should also apply these modification to original JPG at the server-side and output it back to user.

How can I do it? I am using PHP+Imagemagick, but can not find a way to do this conversion. Please help me.

Comment: the server manipulated and the browser manipulated image will never be the same, which to me would kill the usefulness.

Comment: @Dagon You quite not right, please read my answer. I hope it can help to change your opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a great function of ImageMagick which allows us to do anything with brightness and contrast. It is "-level".

But it doesn't allow to apply CSS3 brightness and contrast values directly. Thus I made a great investigation and calculate special formula to transfer CSS brightness and contrast values to "black point" and "white point" parameters of "-level" option. Please check [this page](http://epsiloncool.ru/programmirovanie/php/yarkost-i-kontrastnost-css3-na-storone-servera) (sorry, russian language, but you can use google translate). Roll to the bottom of page if you don't want to read all these equations.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS3 `brightness` filter simply multiplies the color values by the given constant.[[1](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/filters/understanding-css/)][[2](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#brightnessEquivalent)] To achieve the same effect with Imagemagick, use `-evaluate Multiply`[[3](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#evaluate)]. Alternatively, `-function Polynomial`[[4](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#function)] can be used for the same effect. Other features such as `-level`[[5](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#level)][[6](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#levels)] and `-brightness-contrast`[[7](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#brightness-contrast)][[8](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/e93e339c0a44cec16c08d78241f7aa3754485004/MagickCore/enhance.c#L191)] are less appropriate, because they multiply the color by the *inverse* of the given constant.

The CSS property `filter: brightness(80%)` corresponds to the Imagemagick option `-evaluate Multiply .8`.

The CSS property `filter: brightness(120%)` corresponds to the Imagemagick option `-evaluate Multiply 1.2`.

Setting options for Imagemagick in PHP (or migrating from PHP to something better) is an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score -1):

You need to transfer your client brightness settings and then apply them to original JPG with

```
bool Imagick::modulateImage ( float $brightness , float $saturation , float $hue )
```

function. More [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.modulateimage.php)